# Instantiate an Inner class from within a static method of its enclosing Class

Tags: java, inner-classes, scjp

we know that Static contexts can't reference any instance of any type, but what happens with main method, how the following code sample compiles with no problem:

```
public class MyOuter
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        MyOuter mo = new MyOuter(); // gotta get an instance!
        MyOuter.MyInner inner = mo.new MyInner();
        inner.seeOuter();

        //Or

        MyOuter.MyInner inner = new MyOuter().new MyInner();
    } 

    class MyInner
    {
        public void seeOuter(){}
    }
 }
```

isn't it forbidden to instantiate an inner class from within a static context in it's enclosing class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> isn't it forbidden to instantiate an inner class from within a static context in it's enclosing class?

No - it's forbidden to instantiate an inner class *without an instance of the enclosing class*. In your case, you *do* have an instance of the enclosing class:

```
new MyOuter().new MyInner();
```

That's entirely fine.

The only reason you can normally get away without specifying the enclosing class from an instance method is that it's equivalent to

```
// Within an instance method
this.new MyInner();
```

See [section 15.9.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.2) for more details. Your constructor call is a "qualified class instance creation expression".